# Connecting to wampserver MySQL works in PHP but not in vb.NET

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wamp

I have a local wampserver running MySQL. I have successfully connected to it via PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "pyramid";
$password = "pyramid";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

This works perfectly and I get the result "Connected Successfully".

However when I try the same thing in vb.net with this code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ConnectionString As String
        Dim SQLCon As SqlConnection

        ConnectionString =     "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=pyramid;Pwd=pyramid"
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End If
        Finally
            If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

After a long wait of 5 to 10 seconds I get "The system cannot find the file specified"

Both have exactly the same username, password server and database name and still vb.NET refuses to connect.

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of and have exhausted my options. Can you shed any light?

Comment: First ensure that MySQL Connector/NET is installed. and try to connect from VisualStudio, from SQL Server Object Explorer to check connection.

Comment: and read this : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/115753-use-vbnet-to-connect-to-mysql/

Comment: It's perfectly solved now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome !! ;) press that orange Up arrow :) and explain how you solved, for  other people to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the MySQL connector for .NET Framework (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/), then reference the .DLL in your project.

```
Imports MySqL.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim SQLCon As MySqlConnection

    ConnectionString =     "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=pyramid;Pwd=pyramid"
    SQLCon = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End If
    Finally
        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```